# setting variable in header.php but not seen in footer.php

Tags: wordpress

in wordpress ,
 i set a variable in **header.php**

```
<?php
$var= 'anything'
?>
```

but in **footer.php** when I echo it

```
<?php
echo $var;
?>
```

I got no thing printed ... why !>

Comment: Have you tried commenting out everything out between them? My guess is that some extraneous code is overwriting the variable. Or maybe the echo simply isn't executing. Or maybe the variable setting isn't working. What you've given isn't enough to go off of. Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're not in the same scope, as the header and footer files are included in a function's body. So you are declaring a local variable, and referring to another local variable (from another function).

So just declare your variable as global:

```
$GLOBALS[ 'var' ] = '...';
```

Then:

```
echo $GLOBALS[ 'var' ];
```

Answer (score 11):

I know you've already accepted the answer to this question; however, I think there's a much better approach to the variable scope problem than passing vars into the `$GLOBALS` array.

Take the `functions.php` file in your theme for example. This file is included outside the scope of the `get_header()` and `get_footer()` functions. In fact it supersedes anything else you might be doing in your theme (and I believe in the plugin scope as well--though I'd have to check that.)

If you want to set a variable that you'd like to use in your header/footer files, you should do it in your functions.php file rather than polluting $GLOBALS array. If you have more variables that you want to sure, consider using a basic Registry object with getters/setters. This way your variables will be better encapsulated in a scope you can control.

### Registry

Here's a sample `Registry` class to get you started if:

```
<?php
/**
 * Registry
 *
 * @author Made By Me
 * @version v0.0.1
 */
class Registry
{
    # +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    # MEMBERS
    # +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    private $properties = array();

    # +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    # ACCESSORS
    # +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    /**
     * @set     mixed   Objects
     * @param   string  $index  A unique index
     * @param   mixed   $value  Objects to be stored in the registry
     * @return  void
     */
    public function __set($index, $value)
    {
        $this->properties[ $index ] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * @get     mixed   Objects stored in the registry
     * @param   string  $index  A unique ID for the object
     * @return  object  Returns a object used by the core application.
     */
    public function __get($index)
    {
        return $this->properties[ $index ];
    }

    # +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    # CONSTRUCTOR
    # +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    public function __construct()
    {
    }


}
```

Save this class in your theme somewhere, e.g. `/classes/registry.class.php` Include the file at the top of your `functions.php` file: include( get_template_directory() . '/classes/registry.class.php');

### Example Usage

Storing variables:

```
$registry = new Registry();
$registry->my_variable_name = "hello world";
```

Retrieving variables:

```
echo '<h1>' .  $registry->my_variable_name . '</h1>'
```

The registry will accept any variable type.

**Note:** I normally use SplObjectStorage as the internal datastore, but I've swapped it out for a regular ole array for this case.

Comment: As noble as this anti-globals solution is, a $registry variable declared in the functions file is still out side the scope of the footer :(

Comment: ... same thing if it's declared in header.php
=> I just implemented your solution (put the whole registry class in functions.php), and a $registry variable declared in header.php is still empty / null in footer.php :/

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit old question and with a solution voted but I though I should share another option and just found a better solution (that works) without using Globals

```
function fn_your_var_storage( $var = NULL )
{
    static $internal;

    if ( NULL !== $var )
    {
        $internal = $var;
    }

    return $internal;
}

// store the value
fn_your_var_storage( 'my_value' );

// retrieve value
echo fn_your_var_storage(); // print my_value
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

first define your initial variable

```
  $var="something";
```

then use the $_GLOBALS

```
  $_GLOBALS['myvar']=$var;
```

and finally use the global variable in anywhere you want

```
  global $myvar;
```

define string inside the $_GLOBALS as taken as global variable name or use the $_GLOBALS['myvar'] direct into the code without using the global

Comment: NOT $_GLOBALS, It should be $GLOBALS.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove underscore

Answer (score -1):

In wordpress Header, any template, Footer is different functions so you have to declare any varible as a global variable then you can access it .

```
/** header.php **/
<?php
global $xyz;
$xyz="123456"; ?>

/** Template.php or Footer.php **/
<?php 
echo $xyz; ///return 123456
?>
```