# Reusing a PHP variable from a function across files

Tags: php, wordpress, function, include

I have a Wordpress site and I'm looking at 3 relevant files:

- functions.php
- header.php
- index.php (includes header.php)

I'm pulling weather data from an outside feed with a function in `functions.php` and then trying to display that data in two places - once in `header.php` (on every page of the site) and once in `index.php` (a second instance that displays on the home page only). I can get the first instance to display, but I'm having trouble with the second instance

#### functions.php

```
function arctic_valley_weather() {
    function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
        //here's a function that just parses the data. not important
    }

    $fullstring = file_get_contents('http://www.cnfaic.org/library/grabbers/nws_feed.php');
    $parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, 'arctic_valley,', 'marmot,');
    $weatherValues = explode(",",$parsed);
    $dateTime = date_create($weatherValues[0]);

     return array(
      'dateTime' => $dateTime,
      'airTemp' => $weatherValues[1],
      'relHumid' => $weatherValues[2],
      'windSpeed' => $weatherValues[3],
      'windDirection' => $weatherValues[4],
      'windGust' => $weatherValues[5],
    );  
}
```

#### header.php

```
$weatherData = arctic_valley_weather();
echo round($weatherData['airTemp']);
```

This accurately shows the temperature (rounded). Let's say "18".

Trouble comes in `index.php` when I want to just duplicate that exact same result:

```
echo round($weatherData['airTemp']);
```

This one incorrectly shows "0", even though the initial instance is correctly showing 18.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Please try to create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or, a piece of code that demonstrates exactly the problem you are having. Try reducing your code as much as possible and post it again along with your site structure (what file includes what). As it stands,  no one can say what is wrong. Could be many things.

Comment: One thing I can say is that your function shouldn't work at all, unless there are parts of it that you removed. `$weatherValues` isn't defined anywhere and the function wouldn't be able to use it if it was defined outside the function. You would have to use the `global` keyword to use it. And if they are global, it's possible that something is modifying it before it gets to the 2nd function call.

Comment: Thanks - you are right. This wasn't very good. I've rewritten the question to be a lot clearer. (There was more to the function, etc). Not sure if I'm still leaving something out, but I don't think so.

Comment: It looks like Wordpress includes the `header.php` in a function body. This means that all variables defined in `header.php` are out of scope once you leave `header.php`. You can't access the variable in `index.php`, `footer.php`, `page.php`, etc. One solution is to call your function again. But this would make another request to your external resource and would seem wasteful. Or you could assign it to the superglobal `$GLOBALS` array. See this question that had a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434725/setting-variable-in-header-php-but-not-seen-in-footer-php

Comment: So you would have to do something like `$GLOBALS['weatherData'] = arctic_valley_weather();` and then when you want to display it, you would do `echo $GLOBALS['weatherData']` in your `header.php` file and your `index.php` file.

Comment: Thanks @KodosJohnson - this did the trick. If you wanted to add it as an answer, I'd mark it solved.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked for you. I added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Wordpress includes the `header.php` in a function body. This means that all variables defined in `header.php` are out of scope once you leave `header.php`. You can't access the variable in `index.php`, `footer.php`, `page.php`, etc. One solution is to call your function again. But this would make another request to your external resource and that would probably be a waste. Or you could assign it to the superglobal `$GLOBALS` array.

See this similar post: [setting variable in header.php but not seen in footer.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434725/setting-variable-in-header-php-but-not-seen-in-footer-php)

So you would have to do something like this in your `header.php` file:

```
$GLOBALS['weatherData'] = arctic_valley_weather(); 
echo $GLOBALS['weatherData'];
```

And in your `index.php` file you would do this:

```
echo $GLOBALS['weatherData'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try some this like this,
First declare a global variable in your `function.php` file and then assign values to it from your method like this.

```
global $weatherData;

function arctic_valley_weather() {
    global $weatherData;

    function get_string_between($string, $start, $end) {
        //here's a function that just parses the data. not important
    }

    $fullstring = file_get_contents('http://www.cnfaic.org/library/grabbers/nws_feed.php');
    $parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, 'arctic_valley,', 'marmot,');
    $weatherValues = explode(",", $parsed);
    $dateTime = date_create($weatherValues[0]);

    $weatherData = array(
        'dateTime' => $dateTime,
        'airTemp' => $weatherValues[1],
        'relHumid' => $weatherValues[2],
        'windSpeed' => $weatherValues[3],
        'windDirection' => $weatherValues[4],
        'windGust' => $weatherValues[5],
    );
}
```

in `header.php` or `index.php` try accessing `$weatherData` like this:

```
global $weatherData;
echo round($weatherData['airTemp']);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you use global variables ... this is not the standard usage of variables (or you should know exactly what you are doing !)

```
$variable = 'level 0';

function test_1() {
  $variable = 'level 1';
  echo $variable;
}

echo $variable; // will work, because $variable is set to 'level 0'.

test_1(); // will work, because $variable is set to 'level 1' ON THE FUNCTION

function test_2() {
  echo $variable;
}

echo test_2(); // Does not work, because $variable is not set INTERNALLY ON the function
```

Of course, it's possible to use **global** variables ... but is you want to do it, refactor your logic and your code to exclude this method :)